# Multiple pagination in single request using Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I want three different set of paginated records having certain filters in a single query using elastic search.How I can do that?Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that by "three different set of paginated records", you mean all three will have different numbers of paginated record. All three cannot be fetched by a single search, BUT you can always use [Multi Search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html)

The Multi Search API provides us with the facility to execute several search requests within the same API.

This will solve your problem.

Comment: No,Suppose I have 300 records in table with a column price associated with them.Now I want three datasets 
first 10 records with price range 10k to 20 k
first 10 records with price range 30k to 50 k
first 10 records with price range 60k to 80 k
in first request hit then on second hit I want three datasets records from 11 to 20 with same price range.

Comment: So if you are using Multi Search, then within a single request, write 3 sub-requests (see the documentation in the link I gave), with different ranges of price, all 3 of these requests will have same 'size' (=10) and 'from' in a single hit.

Now in the second hit, increment the 'from' part by 10 from application end.